# Route traffic from one VPN tunnel to the other

Tags: networking, routing, site-to-site-vpn, sonicwall, mikrotik

I have three sites with the following interconnections:

Site1 connected to Site2 and Azure site.
Site2 connected only to Site1.

I need to establish a route that goes from Site2 to Azure through Site1. I'm using RouterOS 6.20 on Site1 and SonicWall on Site2.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It should be enough if you create a static route on Site2 that uses the router on Site1 for the Azure-Subnet.

Comment: Nope, that's not working.